# Countdown Timer React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to create a countdown timer that keeps running when app is backgrounded or the user kills the application?

I have already tried this plugin
[react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer), but when user kill s the app, the countdown timer will reset.

Comment: You should store the value by `AsyncStorage` when your app goes to background or killed. Then recalculate when app goes active again.